# Prove $|x+1|\leq 4$ implies that $-4\leq x\leq 2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

How do I prove that if $x$ is a real number, then $\lvert x+1 \rvert\leq 3$ implies that $-4\leq x\leq 2$.

---

EDIT: $\lvert x+1 \rvert\leq 4$ should be $\lvert x+1 \rvert\leq 3$

Comment: It's not true. Try $x=-5$. Then $|x+1|\leq 4$ but $x<-4$.  Perhaps you meant $|x+1|\leq 3$?

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant $3$ not $4$.

Comment: Draw the real line, and a circle of radius $3$ with the center at $-1$ [or (-1,0) to be more precise]. Then, $x$ must be on the real line inside this circle....

Comment: Related older questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442173/what-does-x-2-1-mean and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549429/absolute-value-inequality-help-x1-geq-3 And here is also a more general question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298240/solving-ax-b-gt-c

Answer (score 6):

When one says $|x+a|\leq b$ for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b\ge 0$, it means that
$x+a\leq b$ or $-(x+a)\leq b \Leftrightarrow x+a\geq -b$, which in turns is the same as saying
$$
-b\leq x+a\leq b\\
-b-a\leq x\leq b-a.
$$
In your case, $a=1$ and $b=3$, and so 
$$
-3-1\leq x\leq 3-1,\\
-4\leq x\leq 2
$$

Answer (score 0):

One definition for $\;|\cdot|\;$ is $$|x| = x \max -x$$  Using this definition, and a basic property of $\;\max\;$, we can simply calculate
\begin{align}
& |x+1| \leq 3 \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"the above definition for $\;|\cdot|\;$"} \\
& (x+1) \max -(x+1) \leq 3 \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"basic property of $\;\max\;$"} \\
& x+1 \leq 3 \;\land\; -(x+1) \leq 3 \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify"} \\
& -4 \leq x \leq 2 \\
\end{align}
So we see that actually both statements are equivalent.